# Retrieve particular key from postgresql jsonb using knex

Tags: knex.js, jsonb, strapi

I have *uploads_file* table with *formats* field i need to retrieve only *formats.thumbnail*

upload_file Schema

```
Column  Type    
id  integer Auto Increment [nextval('upload_file_id_seq')]  
name    character varying(255)  
formats jsonb NULL
```

inside strapi i am using knex in the following way to retrive formats.

```
const knex = strapi.connections.default
const resp = await knex
          .select("upf.formats")
          .from("upload_file AS upf")  
return resp
```

it results in

```
[
  {
    "formats": {
      "large": {
        "ext": ".png",
        "url": "/uploads/large_sld1_acb6efc9cc.png",
        "hash": "large_sld1_acb6efc9cc",
        "mime": "image/png",
        "name": "large_sld1.png",
        "path": null,
        "size": 312.82,
        "width": 1000,
        "height": 564
      },
      "small": {
        "ext": ".png",
        "url": "/uploads/small_sld1_acb6efc9cc.png",
        "hash": "small_sld1_acb6efc9cc",
        "mime": "image/png",
        "name": "small_sld1.png",
        "path": null,
        "size": 96.62,
        "width": 500,
        "height": 282
      },
      "medium": {
        "ext": ".png",
        "url": "/uploads/medium_sld1_acb6efc9cc.png",
        "hash": "medium_sld1_acb6efc9cc",
        "mime": "image/png",
        "name": "medium_sld1.png",
        "path": null,
        "size": 192.46,
        "width": 750,
        "height": 423
      },
      "thumbnail": {
        "ext": ".png",
        "url": "/uploads/thumbnail_sld1_acb6efc9cc.png",
        "hash": "thumbnail_sld1_acb6efc9cc",
        "mime": "image/png",
        "name": "thumbnail_sld1.png",
        "path": null,
        "size": 29.8,
        "width": 245,
        "height": 138
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the query works fine. but i need to retrieve only thumbnail out of it. since it is stored as jsonb format not aware of how to retrieve it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `->` operator

```
const knex = strapi.connections.default
const resp = await knex
          .select(
            knex.raw(`upf.formats->'thumbnail' as thumbnail`)
          )
          .from("upload_file AS upf")  
return resp
```

Comment: Great, simple one couldn't figure it out on my own :)